# Finding the limit of a function .

Tags: limits

How can I calculate the following limit:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow a}
\frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{x-a} }{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}
\end{equation*}
I feel that I should multiply by the conjugate, but which conjugate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the above limit doesn't make sense for $x < a$, since the square root in the numerator has a negative argument, but I avoid writing this.

$$
\frac{\sqrt x - \sqrt a + \sqrt{x-a}}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}}\left(\frac{\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{\sqrt{x-a}}  + 1\right) 
$$
Finally, $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{\sqrt{x-a}} = 0$. This is because we can write this as $\frac{\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{x-a} \times \frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x-a}}$. The limit of the first term exists, since it is the derivative of the square root function at $a$. The second term is just $\sqrt{x-a}$, whose limit is zero. So the limit of the product exists and is zero.

Finally,
$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}} \left(\frac{\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{\sqrt{x-a}} + 1\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}
}
$$

since $\sqrt{x+a} \to \sqrt{2a}$ as $x \to a$.

Comment: By the way, forgive me if you do not know the definition of derivative yet. Please tell me if this is the case, then I can modify the answer.

Comment: Why is the $\lim_\limits{x \to a}(\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x-a}})=0$, if by Direct Substitution property its $0/0$?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Direct substitution works *at least* when what you get after direct substitution makes sense. In your case, $\frac 00$ doesn't make sense, so either we must tweak the equation the way I did, to obtain a limit, or see if it is suitable to use L'Hopital's rule, which is another way of simplifying these calculations, and which would also give the right answer here. Direct substitution is also occasionally funny as a practice. For example, would you apply direct substitution to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^4}{x}$, or just seek simplification?

Comment: True I am just wondering if there is a a way to do without L^Hopital's Rule because I am trying to answer and I have like 5 to 6 lines.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky The below answer uses only algebraic tools. It is also nice.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $b=\sqrt{a}$. Then you get:$${y-b+\sqrt{y^2-b^2}\over \sqrt{y^4-b^4}}={\sqrt{y-b}+\sqrt{y+b}\over \sqrt{(y+b)(y^2+b^2)}}$$ So the limit is $1\over \sqrt{2a}$.

Comment: Always love the removal of radicals through substitutions, makes it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could make life a bit simpler using $x=y+a$ which makes
$$\frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{x-a} }{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{a+y}-\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{y (2 a+y)}}$$ Now, use the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor series around $y=0$ to get 
$$\sqrt{a+y}=\sqrt{a}+\frac{y}{2 \sqrt{a}}+O\left(y^2\right)$$
$${\sqrt{y (2 a+y)}}= \sqrt{2a} \sqrt{y}+O\left(y^{3/2}\right)$$ which make finally 
$$\frac{\sqrt{a+y}-\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{y (2 a+y)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a} }+\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2 \sqrt{2}\,a}+O\left(y^1\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached when $y\to 0$.